# Flash object method unavailable after setting display:none

Tags: javascript, css, flash, object, youtube

Here's the situation i'm currently facing.
I have an embedded youtube video as `<object>`. The object exposes javascript API to controle the player.
After setting display:none to the object or the div wrapping the object, the methods become undefined.
Once dispay css property is set back to 'block' - the methods become available again.
I've created a Fiddle showcasing the problem.

[Show case fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borislit/ynuMT/)

I'd like to know why is it happening, and is it possible to monitor object's state and see if its already loaded and ready to use?

Thanks ahead!

**NOTE: The problem can be seen in Chrome**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when using the NPAPI plugin (i.e. not Internet Explorer). You can either move the item off-screen (requires `display:absolute`/`display:relative`), or set the flash object to be 100% size of containing html element and to set the height or width of that element to .01px. Don't use `$(elem).fadeOut` because at the end of the animation, jq sets `display:none`. Instead use `$(elem).fadeTo` which doesn't alter other css attributes. It was also necessary to add a new param

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

to get the fade animation to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ynuMT/4/

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in IE.

My assumption would be that whatever browser you're using thinks it's being clever by "optimising" stuff away. That Flash object is hidden? Well, you couldn't possibly want to do anything with it, no way. [/sarcasm]

I would suggest moving the element off-screen instead of hiding it:

```
#elem {
    position: fixed;
    right: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Apologies: i forgot to mention that the problem can be seen in Chrome (among other browsers).

Comment: Chrome is known for doing stuff like that, unfortunately.